# org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: internal_error(80); TLS 1.3 credentials unhandled ,java 11,TLS version 1.3,BouncyCastle(1.72)

Tags: exception, bouncycastle, java-11, credentials, tls1.3

Due to below piece of code:

```
public int[] getCipherSuites() {
  return Arrays.concatenate(super.getCipherSuites(),
            new int[]
                    {
                            CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
                    });
                    }
}
```

Here super class is AbstractTLSServer.java.

I am getting below exception:

> Exception :org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: internal_error(80); TLS 1.3 credentials unhandled - [MyApp L14 MyApp.run]

I am using java 11, Bouncycastle version 1.72 and TLS version is 1.3

How to bypass this exception?

Answer (score 0):

TLS 1.3 has its own set of Ciphersuites that you need to use: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/TLS1.3#Ciphersuites

Based on this try updating your code to something like this to see if it helps:

```html
public int[] getCipherSuites() {
    // You may or may not need to concat with super.getCipherSuites()
    return new int[] {
        CipherSuite.TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
        CipherSuite.TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
        CipherSuite.TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    };
}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me..Please suggest any other solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The low-level TLS API requires you to take full responsibility for determining the server credentials (i.e. a certificate chain and matching private key). This means overriding TlsServer.getCredentials at minimum (DefaultServer#getCredentials is throwing the exception).

In full generality this is non-trivial since choice of server credentials may depend on several extension sent in the ClientHello. If you only have one set of credentials that you want to use in any case, you could just always return that (for TLS 1.3 it should always be signing credentials i.e. TlsCredentialedSigner).

BTW do you have a specific reason to be using the low-level TLS API directly, instead of just using JSSE (possible with the BCJSSE provider)?

Comment: Hi, I have degraded Bouncycastle version from 1.72 to 1.71.1.

Comment: Bouncy Castle 1.72 is not supported by my system as it enables 1.3 TLS version. My system supports 1.2 or lesser than this.

Comment: You can choose what TLS versions to support by overriding the getSupportedVersions method in your TlsServer subclass. There is no need to downgrade the BC jar for that.